# What will happen if there is large amounts (massive) of electrons in a region?

Tags: electrons

For large amount of hydrogen, they will be bound by gravitation force, start fushion and become a star, how about electrons? Will they also "fuse"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this recent entertaining [What If article](https://what-if.xkcd.com/140/) from XKCD creator Randall Munroe describing the results of having our Moon being replaced by an equivalent mass of electrons. The force of the electrons' mutual repulsion would be twenty orders of magnitude larger than that of their mutual gravity pulling them together. The best quote:

> The amount of energy in our electron Moon, it turns out, is about equal to the total mass and energy of the entire visible universe.

It does not end well.

Comment: Isn't "It does not end well" also a quote? :-)

Comment: Yes, but not from that specific page.

Answer (score 0):

Electrons aren't made up of constituent parts, they are elementary particles. Thus, they will not fuse.

It's also worth noting that the region that fusion occurs at the heart of stars is not only to do with the amount of a particular element, but the heat in the star. The protons have to move with enough energy such that they overcome the repulsion between them due to them having the same charge, and collide.